# Front end link not removing when i disble an Extension in magento

Tags: magento, hyperlink, magento-1.9

I have created a custom extension and give url link in the front end menu, when i disabled this extension from Magento admin side the link is not removing from front end, the link is still showing. what i need to give for removing this link?

```
<default>
   <reference name="top.links">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="retailer"
              >
        <label>Virtual Retailer Signup</label>
        <url>Retailer</url>
        <title>Retailer</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>0</position>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </default>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really disable extensions from the admin panel. The "Disable Modules Output" configuration is a bit misleading, all it does is to skip rendering the blocks and admin menus of the respective module.

The layout updates are still applied, this means every change in the layout that does not use its own blocks, is not affected by "disable module output".

If the extension does not come with its own "disable" configuration, you need to deactivate it entirely, using the module activation file in `app/etc/modules`. Replace

```
<active>true</active>
```

with

```
<active>false</active>
```

Comment: Hi, i have created this extension, but i am not sure, how to disable the front end links when an extension is disabled from back-end.

Comment: A common pattern is `<action method="addLink" ifconfig="group/module/enabled" translate="label title" module="retailer">` and have a system configuration field `group/module/enabled`, which you also can check in other places.